# Set up file launch.json and tasks.json for many files .h and files .cpp (Implement of files .h)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

In my project the schematic of the files is like this:

```
Project
 |__.vscode
 |__main.cpp
 |__Header
    |__Waiter.h
    |__Waiter.cpp
```

In main.cpp, I have: `#include "Header/Waiter.h"`

In Waiter.cpp, I have: `#include "Waiter.h"`

My question is how to set up file `launch.json` to run and debug this project by using F5 (or Ctrl + F5) in VSC?

By the way, with file `task.json` like this, I can `Run built task (Ctrl + Shift + P)`and then run `main.exe`

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}\\Header\\**.cpp",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Use Make, CMake or MSBuild or any other build tool

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you need to create `launch.json` inside the .vscode folder.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried in Linux machine do required changes for windows.

*Note:* `preLaunchTask` value should be equal to `label` value in `tasks.json`.It will build the code and create exe every time before debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but I found problem:

The **label** in file `tasks.json` must be `C/C++: g++.exe build active file!`. And the **preLaunchTask** in file `launch.json` is the same. It's not `C/C++: g++.exe build active file` because we have a `!` at last. It can run now. If anyone knows how it can work by making such a change, please explain why!